# posterior prediction based on a grouping variable from `stan_glm()` in `rstanarm` package?

Tags: r, bayesian, rstan, hierarchical-bayesian, rstanarm

I was wondering how to obtain the posterior prediction based on a grouping variable from `stan_glm()` in `rstanarm` package?

For example, if I have a binary `(0, 1)` coded grouping variable called `"vs"` in my data (base R data: `mtcars`), how can I obtain the prediction for when `vs == 0` and when `vs == 1`?

Here is my R code:

```
library(rstanarm)
fit <- stan_glm(mpg ~., data = mtcars)

posterior_predict(fit, newdata = WHAT SHOULD BE HERE?)
```

Comment: @akrun, that's fine it's a package question, thank you.

Comment: `newdata` should be a dataframe containing sets of values for each predictor that you're interested in. So you need a `newdata` dataframe where some rows have `vs = 0` and some rows have `vs = 1`, you have to figure out what the values of the other predictors should be to give meaningful comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explore the effect of e.g. `vs` on the outcome (in your case `mpg`) you can use `posterior_predict` on the subsets where `vs == 0` and `vs == 1`, respectively:

```
posterior_predict(fit, newdata = subset(mtcars[1:10, ], vs == 0));
```

and

```
posterior_predict(fit, newdata = subset(mtcars[1:10, ], vs == 1));
```

More details are given in `?rstanarm::posterior_predict`.

Comment: @rnorouzian I don't see why. I would always `predict` on the full (new)data; then you can pull out regions of interest in your predictor/parameter space.

Comment: @rnorouzian Ok, I'm beginning to understand; if you're interested in looking at the effect of e.g. `vs` on the outcome `mpg` through the ppd, then you are right in using `posterior_predict` on e.g. `subset(mtcars, vs == 0)` and `subset(mtcars, vs == 1)` separately.

Comment: @rnorouzian ?? Yes I am sure. To quote from `?rstanarm::posterior_predict`: "Drawing from the posterior predictive distribution at interesting values of the predictors also lets us visualize how a manipulation of a predictor affects (a function of) the outcome(s)."